# Guzzle: Convert Regular Request to Asynchronous Request

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I have two guzzle requests in which one needs to finish before the other. I simply use

```
sleep(7)
```

between the two guzzle requests in order to make sure the first request is completely finished before moving on two the second. The issue with this is speed, sometime the first request can be done in a second or two or other times it can be six plus seconds.

Current Code:

```
$client = new Client([
   'base_uri' => 'https://ids.w2p-tools.com/',
]);

$response = $client->request('POST', 'd003/requestpreview.php', [
    'form_params' => [
        'auth' => $auth,
         id' => $id,
        'res' => $res,
        'shownonprintlayer' => $show_non_print_layers
    ]
]);

sleep(7);
```

I have attempted to convert this is a asynchronous request by doing the following:

```
$client = new Client([
   'base_uri' => 'https://ids.w2p-tools.com/',
]);

$request = new Request('POST', 'd003/requestpreview.php', [
    'form_params' => [
        'auth' => $auth,
        'id' => $id,
        'res' => $res,
        'shownonprintlayer' => $show_non_print_layers
    ]
]);

$test = 'None Hit';

$promise = $client->sendAsync($request);

$promise->then(
    function (ResponseInterface $res){
        $test = 'ResponseInterface Hit';
    },
    function (RequestException $e) {
        $test = 'RequestException Hit';
    }
);

$response = $promise->wait();

return $test;
```

This always returns 'None Hit'.

What is being done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`$test` in your closure functions are not global. 
Move the test = none hit to the top, and change the function signature to use the var, as it isn't an object we add & to refer to it by reference, meaning it will change globally too.

```
$test = 'None Hit'; // move up here to make it the default

$promise->then(
    function (ResponseInterface $res) use (&$test) { // use $test by reference
        $test = 'ResponseInterface Hit';
    },
    function (RequestException $e) use (&$test) {
        $test = 'RequestException Hit';
    }
);

$response = $promise->wait();

return $test; // should now have text from one of the closures
```